Construction of an analytic function whose Fourier transformation has compact support
Is there a non-constant real analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ satisfying the following properties?

$f$ vanishes on $x$-axis and $y$-axis;

the Fourier transformation $\hat{f}$ of $f$ has a compact support.



$f=\mathcal{F}(\partial_x\partial_y g(x,y))$ with $g$ a smooth test function should work
